Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't start
Ubuntu 22.04, doesn't start, on the vps. The vps provider says that their is not their fault.
I have attached all the 5 print screens how the terminal, returns me to the starting point, from the tty1 terminal, without starting the os.
1.The print screen number 1, is starting as soon as I click on >_screen in the left panel from the vps
2.For the print screen 2, I press with the mouse on the "Send CTRL+ALT+DEL" on the top of the screen as it is shown in print screen 1.
3.In the print screen 3, I chose first option Debian LINUX/GNU
4.Print screen 4, I CAN NOT choose any of the 3 options
Booting from Hard Disk
GRUB Loading
Welcome to GRUB
It starts automatically with the selected one. Welcome to GRUB
5.Print screen 5, the same, I can not choose any of the 3 options. The same like in print screen 4. At the end, it will automatically turn back to print screen.






Debian 12 was released in August 2024 and is not Ubuntu 22.04. If your system is showing a Debian boot option, either you tried to install Debian over Ubuntu, or some action that is not being communicated was performed

You need to add some context as to how you ended up in this position. Did it ever work etc? Have you just installed it?  The blue is screen is a menu. If you arrow down to the Advanced options and run them does this does it give better/different results? (Append more details to you question.)

@david New installation, for the first time. I will try as soon as possible Advanced Options for Debian, from the second print screen.

Greetings.
Thank you, for your answers.
Excuse me please, I am not so advanced.
I onky use netcup.com vps, just to exercise on it. When I started to set up the vps, I chose to use Ubuntu 22.04. Thank you.

@david Advanced Options for Debian, is the same, is sending me to the same screen from print screen 1. Tried also to login, but it is not working. Any other command please, I could try? Please, remember it i only a vps. Thank you.
